# How to remove extremely annoying Power Bi popup?

Tags: popups, microsoft-powerbi, dax

Since an update, I regularly get a really anoying popup in the DAX editor in powerBI whenever I press ctrl-enter. Does anyone know how to turn this 'feature' off?

This is the popup:

[image: "Tips for using Power BI with a screen reader. / Skip to main content. / Also you can press "?" to show keyboard shortcuts."]

It is particularly annoying considering it can't be closed or ignored with escape as it loses focus as soon as it appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pop-up is non-removable but the alternative I found is **shift-enter** instead of the previous alt-enter.

Answer (score 0):

Using alt-enter inserts a blank line - is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Alt-enter indeed inserts a blank line but ignores indentation. Ctrl-enter does keep the right indentation level while adding a new line but since a while also produces this annoying help popup with it.